# Placeholder in Types.Text in keystone

Tags: keystonejs

Help, Every one I am new in keystone while defining the model I am not able to put the placeholder text in the TYPES.TEXT model. I do not know the syntex. Please help me.

```
 product.add({

  title: {type: String, required: true},

   description: {type: Types.Text,},


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/options/

All field types in Keystone have several common options one of which is setting the default value for the field.  If you add default: 'Your Default Text Here" the default value for that filed if nothing else is submitted would be Your Default Text Here.

```
product.add({

  title: {type: String, required: true},

   description: {type: Types.Text, default: 'Your Default Text Here'},


 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?